# Will PHP's gethostname and gethostbyname always work?

Tags: php, networking, gethostbyname

I'm developing a PHP app which needs to be locked down to a particular server IP address so that people cannot easily copy it to other servers. The application will be installed on an internal server at the client's office.

I have an encoded license file with the allowed server IP address stored in it, and on the login page I want to check that this matches the IP of the server.

To do this I use the following code:

```
if(getHostByName(getHostName()) != $licensedServerIp){
  throw new Exception("The server's IP address does not match that in your license file.");
}
```

This works nicely on my development machine, but are there any situations that I need to look out for where this function would fail? I have no idea what the function is actually doing in the background - could certain network issues stop this from working?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of this: this would be checking a *local* IP address like `192.168.0.15`, right? That would mean that any internal change in the local network structure will break your application, and one could run any number of illegal copies in other local networks as long as they get the server IP right. What would this achieve except for making life more difficult for the customer?

Comment: It will fail if the server does not have an adequate DNS set up. It will also fail if someone opens your source code and removes the check. PHP is an open source language, it's very difficult to lock an application down like this - concentrate on making money from support, not by attempting to create a foolproof licensing system (because there isn't one).

Comment: I think you raise some very valid points! Is there any other way of stopping PHP code running on other servers?

Comment: Also I have used an encoder to encode the PHP source.

Comment: In a word, no. There are all sorts of approaches to this that I have seen over the years, and I have never seen one that couldn't be fairly easily circumvented by someone who knows what they are doing. Obfuscating/encoding the source code doesn't really help, they can all be reversed fairly trivially.

Answer (score -1):

No.
Please follow the links given below:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63730
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=8754

Its recommended, not to use it in production sites

Comment: "Its recommended, not to use it in production sites" - taken out of context. Additionally: answering is not just about pasting links.

Comment: @M.M. I have mentioned what I thought can be useful. And, my answer doesn't have just links. What if my answer has three links that can be useful. Please make a note that all three links I have mentioned are from official PHP site. Moreover, I have mentioned what is recommended and its answered back in 2012.